# error reading protobuf message as string from file

Tags: protocol-buffers

I intend to read protobuf data from a file and use it in my code. I tried to do some reverse engineering and filled the data into my file and dumbed the string in a log file. I read this log file now and change values of fields and read it in a string using file handling. However it doesn't seem to work. Is there some problem with my code.

```
std::ifstream myprotobuf("/root/testfile.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
if (myprotobuf)
{
    std::string string_in_file;
    myprotobuf.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    contents.resize(myprotobuf.tellg());
    myprotobuf.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    myprotobuf.read(&string_in_file[0], contents.size());
    myprotobuf.close();
    RealMsg -> ParseFromString (string_in_file);
}
```

Comment: You should provide more information, such as: 1) how does it not work and 2) what is the actual .proto definition and data in the testfile.